# How to check value of div property in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a line in my component like so...

```
    <div className="progress" mx-auto data-value={100 - (100 * session.timeRemaining) / (session.label === "Focusing" ? focusDuration * 60: breakDuration * 60)}>
```

I want to do something like this...

```
    <div className="progress" mx-auto data-value={100 - (100 * session.timeRemaining) / (session.label === "Focusing" ? focusDuration * 60: breakDuration * 60)}>

 if (data-value > 0) {do stuff}
```

How do I monitor / check for the value of my divs data-value attribute?

Comment: Why not use a variable to store that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute` function.

```
<div className="progress" mx-auto data-value={100 - (100 * session.timeRemaining) / (session.label === "Focusing" ? focusDuration * 60: breakDuration * 60)}>
```

```
document.querySelector(".progress").getAttribute('value');
```